# Doctrine 2 ManyToOne with Join Table

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to map a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship that uses a join table. The mapping I have is not taking, and I get an error that article_id is not set in the media table.

```php
class Media
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Document", inversedBy="media")
     * @JoinTable(name="articles_x_media", referencedColumnName="id")
     * joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="bid_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * )
     */
    protected $document;
}

class Document
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="document"))
     * @JoinTable(name="articles_x_media", referencedColumnName="id")
     * joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $media;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There's a specific paragraph in the documentation about [`OneToMany` mapping with join table](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table).

Anyway, what you probably want is an [uni-directional `ManyToMany` association](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).

Also, `@OneToMany` does not come with a `@JoinTable`, and the same for `@ManyToOne` either.

Comment: Just saw this, will check these out and give feedback/accept soon.

Comment: @Shroder You never posted any feedback. Can you please post your findings?

Comment: What if I want a bidirectional `one-to-many` or `many-to-one` with join table. Is this possible? If I use the same `many-to-many` with unique constraint. How does that look on the one/single side? Should I use something like $collection[0] on the getter to make the Collection to a Singleton? Sadly enough these cases are badly documented in Doctrine specs.

Comment: @Wilt they are not documented because the documentation doesn't provide you with complete use-cases, only with the basics, which is exactly what the documentation should do. The links provided in this response actually lead to your use-case as well.

Comment: All the links provided are no longer available

Comment: Thanks @Ocramius PS: I have seen that the doctrine docs have been broken for a while now, like the tabs (PHP/XML) etc are broken, etc. Just a heads up. Chrome browser on MacOS Mojave

Comment: Please report that to https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine-website - I'm not directly working on it myself, but some other folks are putting a lot of effort in it :)