# Doctrine OneToMany relationship mapping missing inversedBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4, doctrine-mapping

I am attempting to create a OneToMany relationship between two of my entities. One `Customer` can be a member of many `Club`s.

These are my entities:

```
class Club
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="clubs")
     */
    private $customer;
```

```
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @var Club[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Club", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="customer")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_club",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="club_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    private $clubs;
```

Rather than adding a field to the `club` table, I have created a `customer_club` table which looks like:

```
_________________________
| customer_id | club_id |
_________________________
| 1           | 16      |
| 1           | 90      |
| 1           | 72      |
_________________________
```

These relationship definitions are wrong because when I load my Symfony 3.4 application I get the following error:

> [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\OneToMany declared on property
>   AppBundle\Entity\Customer::$clubs does not have a property named
>   "inversedBy". Available properties: mappedBy, targetEntity, cascade,
>   fetch, orphanRemoval, indexBy

What have I done wrong?

Comment: check out the docs on this https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

Comment: if you would read the error message, you would see that OneToMany can't have `inversedBy`, instead it has `mappedBy`. This is, because `Club` is the owning side and maps that relation with its `customer` property (which is what you tell Doctrine in the annotation on `Customer::$clubs`). Every relation must have an owning side, so naturally not both sides can have an `inversedBy`.

Comment: Thanks @BrucieAlpha the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444822/691505 and the docs posted helped with with this one. A uni-directional ManyToMany was the answer here. One crucial part I was missing was doing a `addClub` rather than `setClub` on the `Customer.

Comment: @crmpicco as far as i know you need to have either setEntities and getEntities or  addEntity removeEntity getEntities methods available